# Find and Replace DYNAMIC text in word using excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

We can replace static text in word document using

```
Dim obj_word As New Word.Application
Dim doc_word As Word.Document

Set doc_word = obj_word.Documents.Open(file_path)
doc_word.Content.Find
    .Text = "TEXT1"
    .Replacement.Text = "TEXT2"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
End With
```

But what if dynamic text need to be replaced with another text??

For example I am creating a word template and the dynamic word is {Sheet1-D8}

I want to replace this with the word present in excel sheet1 range D8.

Could someone please help?

Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Please, use the next way: `Dim strReplace As String` `strReplace = Sheet1.Range("D8").value` Then use: `.Replacement.Text = strReplace`... If I correctly could understand what you say, even if it looks strange... "the dynamic word is {Sheet1-D8}" followed by "I want to replace this with the word present in excel sheet1 range D8.". My suggestion replaces `"TEXT1"` with the value of "D8" in `Sheet1`...

Comment: Hi Fanu, the excel value present in D8 cell keeps changing every day. I need to fetch the text {sheet1-D8}  from word document. So that i can decode using code and get the replacement text dynamically..

Comment: Note: D8 is just one cell. The word template has more than 100 dynamic texts which needs to be repalced with whatever code (range value) has been provided

Comment: I am not able to understand what "to fetch the text {sheet1-D8}" should mean... Should there be such a text, or something different but on the same pattern, from where to extract "D8" range of the active workbook "Sheet1" sheet? If my supposition is correct, please provide at least one or two such examples. Something as `{sheet2-F8}` should it mean `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F8")`?

Comment: Isn't the above understanding what you try accomplishing? If not, can you better clarify what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Everyone for your responses. But I found the solution to my problem via below link. (Trick was to use the wild cards)

[Find string in doc using wildcards; return full string VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376093/find-string-in-doc-using-wildcards-return-full-string-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Try the next way, please:

```
Dim strAddr As String, strReplace as String, arrAdr
strAddr = "{sheet1-D8}"
arrAdr = split(strAddr,"-")
strReplace = Worksheets(mid(2,arrAdr(0))).Range(left(arrAdr(1), len(arrAdr(1) -1)).value
```